# Left join using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using the following PDO query:

```
  <?php
            $cadena =   $_SESSION[Region];

// We Will prepare SQL Query


       $STM = $dbh->prepare("SELECT  `id_mesero`, `nombre_mesero`,`alias_mesero`, `rest_mesero` FROM tbmeseros WHERE cadena_mesero='$cadena'");
// For Executing prepared statement we will use below function
    $STM->execute();
// we will fetch records like this and use foreach loop to show multiple Results
    $STMrecords = $STM->fetchAll();
    foreach($STMrecords as $row)
        {
```

The value from the 'rest_mesero' field is the index from the table 'tbrestaurantes'.

I would need to join some fields values from 'tbrestaurantes' to the PDO query, but I don't know how to do it using PDO.

Any help is welcome.

UPDATED QUESTION TEXT

This is my proposal for the query :

```
$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbmeseros LEFT JOIN tbrestaurantes ON tbmeseros.rest_mesero = tbrestaurantes.id_restaurante WHERE tbmeseros.cad_mesero = ?");
```

But is show an error:

Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in /.../AdminMeseros.php on line 80

Line 80 is

```
$STM->execute();
```

This is my updated query:

```
              <?php
            $cadena =   $_SESSION[Region];



       $STM =$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbmeseros LEFT JOIN tbrestaurantes ON tbmeseros.rest_mesero = tbrestaurantes.id_restaurante WHERE tbmeseros.cad_mesero = ?");
       $STM->bindParam(1, $cadena);
// For Executing prepared statement we will use below function
    $STM->execute(array($cadena));
// we will fetch records like this and use foreach loop to show multiple Results
    $STMrecords = $STM->fetchAll();
    foreach($STMrecords as $row)
        {
```

And here table's screenshots:

For tbmeseros:

[image]

For tbrestaurantes:
[image]
[image]

The value of $cadena is 'HQ3'.

Comment: post both the table structures along with which fields you need to select.

Comment: There's nothing special about doing it with PDO. You just put the SQL in the argument to `prepare()`.

Comment: Why do you have a variable in your SQL? When you use PDO, you should use `:parameter`, and use `bindParam()` to link the variable to it.

Comment: @Barmar, I have included my proposal for the SQL in the question.

Comment: It is OK, it works, the last error was the field name cad_mesero, it should be cadena_mesero. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put a parameter in the SQL, you need to supply the value for the parameter. There are two ways to do that:

1) Call `bindParam()`:

```
$STM->bindParam(1, $cadana);
```

2) Provide the values when calling `execute()`:

```
$STM->execute(array($cadana));
```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, after doing what you say, the error is gone, but the query is empty. It should show one record.

Comment: then the query isn't finding anything that matches `$cadana`.

Comment: I have checked the tables and I am sure that there is a record from tbmeseros which matches the query. I have included the data on my question and my proposal of query. May be you could find the problem

Comment: It is OK, it works, the last error was the field name cad_mesero, it should be cadena_mesero. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I noticed that discrepancy, I thought you just abbreviated it when you copied to SO, because otherwise it would cause an error message.

Comment: ,thank you again. I am still trying to learn from people like you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fill the ? in the query:

```
$q = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbmeseros LEFT JOIN tbrestaurantes ON tbmeseros.rest_mesero = tbrestaurantes.id_restaurante WHERE tbmeseros.cad_mesero = ?");
$q->bindValue( 1, 'x' );
$q->execute();
print_r( $q->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
```

In prepare you can use '?' and then bindValue to attach an escaped value to the query. Your query doesn't appear to have this and that is the cause of the error.